# Static Array in Abstract Class

Tags: c++

I have an abstract class on which I would like to include as a static variable an array of pointers for that same class. This array would be later used by the derived classes.

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual int someValue() = 0;
    static Base* Bases[100];

    void Startup() {
      Bases[2] = this; // just a test
    };
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    virtual int someValue() {return 10};
};
```

Yet, when compiling, I get the following error: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386 "Bases", referenced from: Base::Startup()`.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Members declared `static` have to be defined *outside* the class.

Comment: You should consider using `std::vector`. It's a lot less work.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared your array `Bases`, but you have not defined it. You need to define it somewhere else, preferably on a cpp file:

```
Base* Base::Bases[100];
```

Comment: That simple? Wow, I can't believe I took so long to figure it out. Thank you!